# Drawing closed polygons from simple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I am trying to create a program that allows users to draw different types of shapes by drawing simple lines using Pyqt5.

**The program** must detect if a shape is closed and then automatically fill the area inside of it with a defined color(for example red in this code)

**Problem:** The program only understands closure of the shape if the lines are drawn in a specific order, if someone can help me make this function work regardless of the order that which the lines are drawn?

**I** will include an example below for you to understand what I mean better along with the code.tnx

[image: Works]

[image: doesnt work]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsLineItem, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QBrush, QColor , QPolygonF

class UserLineItem(QGraphicsLineItem):
    pass

class MeasuredGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.line_start = None
        self.current_line = None
        self.current_shape = []

        self.draw_background_grid()

        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.TextAntialiasing, True)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.show_context_menu)

    def draw_background_grid(self):
        dotted_line_pen = QPen(Qt.lightGray, 1, Qt.DotLine)

        self.scene.addLine(-500, 0, 500, 0, dotted_line_pen)
        self.scene.addLine(0, -500, 0, 500, dotted_line_pen)

        grid_spacing = 25
        for i in range(-500 + grid_spacing, 501 - grid_spacing, grid_spacing):
            self.scene.addLine(i, -500, i, 500, dotted_line_pen)
            self.scene.addLine(-500, i, 500, i, dotted_line_pen)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            if isinstance(item, UserLineItem):
                pass
            else:
                self.line_start = self.snap_to_grid(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
                if self.line_start.x() < -500 or self.line_start.x() > 500 or \
                        self.line_start.y() < -500 or self.line_start.y() > 500:
                    return
                self.current_line = UserLineItem()
                self.current_line.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5))  # Set pen width
                self.scene.addItem(self.current_line)
                self.current_shape.append(self.line_start)

        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            # Only show context menu if right-clicked on a UserLineItem
            item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            if isinstance(item, UserLineItem):
                self.show_context_menu(event.pos())

        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.line_start and self.current_line:
            end_point = self.snap_to_grid(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            if end_point.x() < -500 or end_point.x() > 500 or \
                    end_point.y() < -500 or end_point.y() > 500:
                return
            self.current_line.setLine(self.line_start.x(), self.line_start.y(),
                                      end_point.x(), end_point.y())

        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.line_start:
            if self.current_line and self.line_start != self.current_shape[0]:
                end_point = self.snap_to_grid(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
                if end_point.x() < -500 or end_point.x() > 500 or \
                        end_point.y() < -500 or end_point.y() > 500:
                    return

                self.current_shape.append(end_point)

                if len(self.current_shape) > 2 and self.current_shape[0] == self.current_shape[-1]:
                    self.fill_shape()
                    self.current_shape = []  # Reset the current shape

            self.line_start = None
            self.current_line = None

        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def snap_to_grid(self, point):
        grid_spacing = 25
        x = round(point.x() / grid_spacing) * grid_spacing
        y = round(point.y() / grid_spacing) * grid_spacing
        return QPointF(x, y)

    def fill_shape(self):
        poly = self.scene.addPolygon(QPolygonF(self.current_shape), QPen(Qt.black), QBrush(Qt.red))

    def show_context_menu(self, pos):
        item = self.itemAt(pos)
        if isinstance(item, UserLineItem):
            global_pos = self.mapToGlobal(pos)
            context_menu = QMenu(self)
            delete_action = context_menu.addAction('Delete')
            action = context_menu.exec_(global_pos)

            if action == delete_action:
                self.scene.removeItem(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = MeasuredGraphicsView()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please take your time to [edit] your post by properly checking the indentation in the post preview, as right now your code is not runnable and it's difficult to understand the hierarchy of `if/elif/else` blocks.

Comment: Stack overflow seems to mess up the tabs of some lines when i paste the code, I tried to put them in order as much as possible.

Comment: please test again,it should work now

Comment: The simplest solution is to not use tabs: for the purposes of your post (even if you don't use that in your "real" code) replace tabs with two spaces, so your code is both concise, and not dependent on magical tab spacing. (the code in your post should be the [mcve] of your real code, which _can_ be, but often isn't, "the real code")

Comment: One thing I can strongly recommend is to change click handling: don't _draw_ things on click, instead just record the coordinates in a list, and then draw things based on that coordinate list instead. That way drawing a polygon after placing several points is simply a "start path", "for each coordinate: place vertex", and "end path".

Answer (score 0):

There are many logical issues in your implementation, but the most important one is here:

```py
if len(self.current_shape) > 2 and self.current_shape[0] == self.current_shape[-1]:
```

The above just checks if there are at least 3 points and if the last added point is identical to the first one. With these simple conditions, the following situations would fail to a certain level:

- at least one line doesn't start at the end of the previous one, failing to call `fill_shape()` if it's the last line, or creating a different shape;
- create a second line with the end point that coincides with the start point of the first line:

  - `fill_shape()` would be called with an invalid point order;
  - even if you wanted to create a triangle by implicitly use the 3 vertexes, that would prevent the possibility to create polygons with more than 3 sides;
- create any other line that starts or ends at an existing vertex (which already has two lines);
- create a closed polygon while other *unrelated* lines also exist;

In order to create a valid "standard" polygon (see [closed polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain#Closed)), you need to respect the following:

- at least 3 vertexes (points) should exist;
- each vertex has to be unique and only shared by exactly two lines (segments), being it the end of one segment and the start of the other;
- if more than 3 vertexes exist, their order must be reconstructed by considering each segment as a vector (a directional segment, explicitly going from `P1` to `P2`), with each end point colliding with the start point of only one other vector;

The last aspect is fundamental: given a number of vertexes `n`, the possible amount of polygons is `(n-1)!/2` (`!` is for [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial): `4! = 24` as in `4! == 4 × (4 - 1) × (4 - 2)`, etc.). 4 points can result into 3 different iterations/polygons, 5 points give 12 polygons and so on.

For instance, given 4 arbitrary points, you can get the following results:

[image: Possible iterations of a 4 point polygon]

Now, let's get to the point in order (pun intended).

You are probably interested in creating a closed polygon (no matter the side count) as you would physically draw it on paper: you imagine it in your mind and you draw its lines, even if they are not in the order of the final polygon. In order to achieve this, you have to create a "map" of points and eventually create the closed polygon as soon as all points become actual vertexes (aka: each point is *both* the start and end of one segment).

One possibility to achieve this is to create a dictionary that uses vertexes as keys and line items as values. To each real vertex corresponds exactly two line items, and as long as all vertexes have exactly two line items, you have a closed polygon.

Once a new segment has been finalized, we try to create a consecutive path with the following procedure:

1. take one of the two points of the segment as a reference (it doesn't matter which one: as long as a vertex only corresponds to just one or two vectors, the other point will be eventually reached for a closed path);
2. check if the point corresponds to at least 2 lines: if it doesn't, then there is no closed polygon, so we exit the whole procedure;
3. get the lines (segments), exclude the current one and check the point of the other segment that is not the current vertex;
4. if the other point of the other segment is the reference (used in `1.`), then the path is closed; otherwise, restart from 2;

The following code is a modified version of yours that implements the above. Note that:

- QPointF is not hashable (so it can't be used for dictionary keys); I use `x()` and `y()` values instead;
- for simplicity, I added some helper functions to the `UserLineItem` subclass so that it can directly access the `QLineF` getter and setter functions;
- I used `setSceneRect()` to properly set scene boundaries;
- it doesn't make a lot of sense to use the `CustomContextMenu` policy within the same widget, unless really required by external reasons; I replaced it with the [`contextMenuEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuEvent) override instead;

```py
class UserLineItem(QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5))

    def p1(self):
        return self.line().p1()

    def p2(self):
        return self.line().p2()

    def setP1(self, p):
        line = self.line()
        if line.p1() != p:
            line.setP1(p)
            self.setLine(line)

    def setP2(self, p):
        line = self.line()
        if line.p2() != p:
            line.setP2(p)
            self.setLine(line)


class MeasuredGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    gridSpacing = 25
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(-500, -500, 1000, 1000)

        self.currentLine = None
        self.vertexLines = {}

    def drawBackground(self, qp, rect):
        normal = QPen(Qt.lightGray, 1, Qt.DotLine)
        dark = QPen(Qt.black, 1, Qt.DotLine)

        rect &= self.scene.sceneRect()
        left, top, right, bottom = rect.getCoords()

        qp.save()

        x = left // self.gridSpacing * self.gridSpacing
        while x <= right:
            if x == 0:
                qp.setPen(dark)
            else:
                qp.setPen(normal)
            qp.drawLine(QLineF(x, top, x, bottom))
            x += self.gridSpacing

        y = top // self.gridSpacing * self.gridSpacing
        while y <= bottom:
            if y == 0:
                qp.setPen(dark)
            else:
                qp.setPen(normal)
            qp.drawLine(QLineF(left, y, right, y))
            y += self.gridSpacing

        qp.restore()

    def removeCurrentLine(self):
        if self.currentLine:
            self.removeLineItem(self.currentLine)
            self.currentLine = None

    def removeLineItem(self, lineItem):
        if not isinstance(lineItem, QGraphicsLineItem):
            return
        line = lineItem.line()
        for p in (line.p1(), line.p2()):
            key = p.x(), p.y()
            if key in self.vertexLines:
                items = self.vertexLines[key]
                if lineItem in items:
                    items.remove(lineItem)
                if not items:
                    del self.vertexLines[key]
        self.scene.removeItem(lineItem)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        item = self.itemAt(pos)
        if isinstance(item, UserLineItem):
            menu = QMenu(self)
            menu.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)

            deleteAction = menu.addAction('Delete')
            action = menu.exec_(event.globalPos())

            if action == deleteAction:
                self.removeLineItem(item)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if self.currentLine and event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            # discard the current line
            self.removeCurrentLine()
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            p = self.snapToGrid(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            lines = self.vertexLines.setdefault((p.x(), p.y()), [])
            if len(lines) == 2:
                return
            self.currentLine = UserLineItem(QLineF(p, p))
            self.scene.addItem(self.currentLine)
            lines.append(self.currentLine)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if self.currentLine:
            endPoint = self.snapToGrid(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            if not self.scene.sceneRect().contains(endPoint):
                return
            self.currentLine.setP2(endPoint)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        if not self.currentLine or event.button() != Qt.LeftButton:
            return

        if self.currentLine.line().isNull():
            # empty line (start and end are identical)
            self.removeCurrentLine()
            return

        endPoint = self.snapToGrid(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
        if not self.scene.sceneRect().contains(endPoint):
            # out of scene boundaries
            self.removeCurrentLine()
            return

        current = self.currentLine.line()
        startPoint = current.p1()
        key = endPoint.x(), endPoint.y()

        if not key in self.vertexLines:
            # new vertex
            self.vertexLines[key] = [self.currentLine]
            self.currentLine = None
            return

        lineItems = self.vertexLines[key]

        if len(lineItems) == 2:
            # the point already has two lines (is real a vertex)
            self.removeCurrentLine()
            return

        other = lineItems[0].line()
        if (
            other == current or (
                other.p2() == startPoint
                and other.p1() == endPoint
            )
        ):
            # a similar segment already exists
            self.removeCurrentLine()
            return

        lineItems.append(self.currentLine)

        self.fillShape(self.currentLine)

        self.currentLine = None

    def fillShape(self, reference):
        current = reference
        p = current.p1()

        polygon = [p] # the possible polygon
        toRemove = set() # line items that may be eventually removed

        while True:
            lineItems = self.vertexLines[p.x(), p.y()]
            if len(lineItems) == 1:
                # open path, ignore
                return

            toRemove |= set(lineItems)
            firstItem, lastItem = lineItems

            if firstItem == current:
                nextItem = lastItem
            else:
                nextItem = firstItem

            if nextItem == reference:
                # closed path, finalize polygon
                break

            if nextItem.p1() == p:
                p = nextItem.p2()
            else:
                p = nextItem.p1()

            polygon.append(p)
            current = nextItem

        self.scene.addPolygon(QPolygonF(polygon), QPen(Qt.black), QBrush(Qt.red))

        # remove line items and their vertexes
        for item in toRemove:
            self.removeLineItem(item)

    def snapToGrid(self, point):
        return QPointF(
            round(point.x() / self.gridSpacing) * self.gridSpacing, 
            round(point.y() / self.gridSpacing) * self.gridSpacing
        )
```